# Check if parking space is full with Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am trying to make an autonomous car park into a parking lot where if there is a blue line a slot is considered full and if there isn't it is considered empty:[image: IMG_0352.png]
I have tried many things from basic color detection to edge detection and even feature matching:

[image: Screen_Shot_2018-08-09_at_12.57.01_PM.png]

Code I am currently using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera import PiCamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
img = cv2.imread("CAT2.png")

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (320, 240)
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 240))


sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp_image, desc_image = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)

index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
search_params = dict()
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
for f in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port = True):
    frame = rawCapture.array
    cropped = frame[0:80, 0:320]
    grayframe = cv2.cvtColor(cropped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    kp_grayframe, desc_grayframe = sift.detectAndCompute(grayframe, None)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_image, desc_grayframe, k=2)


    good_points = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.5*n.distance:
            good_points.append(m)

    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img, kp_image, grayframe, kp_grayframe, good_points, grayframe)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.imshow("grayFrame", grayframe)
    cv2.imshow("img3", img3)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However nothing I try works!  I would prefer it if you would explain how I can do it instead of doing it for me.

Comment: Hi @huvarda, what have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: Here is my code.

Comment: Are you trying to detect a blue line, or are you trying to detect a car and then draw a blue line?

Comment: I am trying to detect a blue line

Comment: I think I went a bit overboard with feature detecting as there aren't that many unique features

Comment: Then don't convert your image to grayscale. You're losing all your colour information! Keep it as RGB/BGR or convert into LUV colour space and just look for pixels that are blue

Comment: but the parking spaces next to it are also visible

Comment: Step one: Segment the image into individual parking bays based on the white lines, or maybe just do it once by hand if the camera doesn't move. Step 2 find all the blue pixels in each parking bay, and see if they form a straight line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177720/discussion-between-huvarda-and-spoonless).